# stack overflow on recursive function haskell

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

Here is one implementation of power function in Haskell. But I have stack overflow error. No idea how to fix

```
power''::Integer->Integer->Integer
power'' _ 0=1
power'' 1 _=1
power'' n k
    |even k = power'' (n*n)  (k `div` 2)
    |otherwise = n * power'' n k-1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
|otherwise = n * power'' n k-1
```

this is

```
|otherwise = (n * power'' n k)-1
```

and hence you recurse with the same arguments forever.

Comment: well I have to `|otherwise = n * power'' n (k-1)`

Answer (score 0):

--Found my problem

```
 |otherwise = n * power'' n (k-1)
```